# Where do I get urdf_sim_tutorial package

Tags: ros, urdf, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20a%20URDF%20in%20Gazebo)

One of the instructions is to run:

```
 roslaunch urdf_sim_tutorial gazebo.launch
```

However I do not have urdf_sim_tutorial package.

I tried to install it, but it failed:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-urdf_sim_tutorial
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-urdf_sim_tutorial
```

Searched it on github, but couldn't find it.

Can anyone tell me where can I get the package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269233/where-do-i-get-urdf_sim_tutorial-package/) by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 582 on 2017-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am doing this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20a%20URDF%20in%20Gazebo)
>
> One of the instructions is to run:
>
> ```
> roslaunch urdf_sim_tutorial gazebo.launch
> ```
>
> However I do not have urdf_sim_tutorial package.

That seems like an omission from the tutorial (and would be nice if you could correct it).

> I tried to install it, but it failed:
>
> ```
> ~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-urdf_sim_tutorial
> ```

That is almost correct: underscores (`_`) in ROS package names are replaced with dashes (`-`) in Debian/Ubuntu package names. The following should work:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-urdf-sim-tutorial
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-21**:
This happens with some of the tutorials that I've encountered. You're instructed to install the package in the first of the series so if you're going through them from start to finish you're fine. If you just jump into one from the middle you may end up a little lost.